Black gaps between tiles after qgis:tilesxyzdirectory
After adding satellite images and using qgis:tilesxyzdirectory, I discovered gaps between the tiles:

I used the following parameters:
res = processing.run("qgis:tilesxyzdirectory", {
    'ANTIALIAS' : False,
    'BACKGROUND_COLOR': QColor(0, 0, 0, 0),
    'DPI' : 96, 
    'EXTENT' :'-413332.5539,2852174.3044,-154005.2915,4334168.0883 []',
    'HTML_ATTRIBUTION' : '', 
    'HTML_OSM' : False, 
    'HTML_TITLE' : '', 
    'METATILESIZE' : 20, 
    'OUTPUT_DIRECTORY' : '/data/tiles', 
    'OUTPUT_HTML' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 
    'QUALITY' : 75, 
    'TILE_FORMAT' : 0, 
    'TILE_HEIGHT' : 256, 
    'TILE_WIDTH' : 256, 
    'TMS_CONVENTION' : True,   
    'ZOOM_MAX' : 13, 
    'ZOOM_MIN' : 10
})

What could be the problem?

Which satellite images are you using?

Only images from Landsat 8

According to the documentation, this is PNG (0 — PNG, 1 — JPG)
